# Path that return a unique node and no relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher query:

```
MATCH p=(no {name:'nodeName'})<-[:enfant*0..]-(parent:application) 
unwind nodes(p) as n unwind relationships(p) as r
with collect( distinct {id: id(n), name: n.name, labels: labels(n)}) as nl,
collect( distinct {source: id(startnode(r)), target: id(endnode(r))}) as rl 
RETURN {nodes: nl, links: rl}
```

This request retrun the path between a node and all his parents and then transform into d3js format(nodes&links).
i have these cases :

1. the start node is not an application --> the path return all nodes and relations so the response is good
2. the start node is already an application, so the path return this node and then i have this response:

   {"nodes":[],"links":[]}

and normally I will have :

```
{"nodes":[{id: 111, name: 'nodeName', labels:['application']}],"links":[]}
```

When i test without relationships like this :

```
MATCH p=(no {name:'nodeName'})<-[:enfant*0..]-(parent:application) 
WITH p
unwind nodes(p) as n 
with collect( distinct {id: id(n), name: n.name, labels: labels(n)}) as nl
RETURN {nodes: nl}
```

i have the good reponse :

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"nodeName","id":111,"labels":["application"]}]}
```

so the problem is in the collect() with relationships because its empty, i don't know how can i fix that ?
Thank you.

Comment: I cannot simulate your problem. When I run a query similar to your example, I am getting non-empty links. For example:  "links":[{"source":70430,"target":38099},{"source":74508,"target":38099}].  Are you sure you are getting empty links in your neo4j browser?  or in your java/python application?  What is the version of your neo4j desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that the path return a unique node so relationships will be an empty list and when you UNWIND an empty list, it wipes out the rows
if you want you find the discussion here : https://community.neo4j.com/t/path-that-return-a-unique-node-and-no-relationship/34719/2